# JNI error, please check your instalation (Running a JAR file)

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface

This is not a duplicate! So I created a jar file and with manifest indicating the main-class. But when I try to run it with

> java -jar app.jar

It prints in my CMD:
"Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your instalation and try again.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Food has been compiled by a more recent version of the java run time (55) this version of the java runtime recognizes versions up to 52"

Weird thing is that I can compile and run java and class programs in CMD. But running JAR files, I can't.

I have jdk1.8.0_201 and jre1.8.0_201. Which I'm almost sure it's the latest. Atleast jre because when I open "configure java" program, and go to update tab and click "update now", it says: "you already have the latest java platform on this system. Shouldnt I keep the versions of jre and jdk equal?

Also I would like to have some clarification of the numbers of these jre and jdk. First in my ambient variables, all I have is jdk 1.8 and jre 1.8 just like above, so how can I tell me I have a more recent version?

So according to this post, [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

if I have version 52 which is Java SE 8.0, why when install jdk, it says 1.8.0_201 and not 8.0? Tha's the same question of why microsoft skipped microsoft 9...

And yes I have java 11 (55) but it's not even in ambient variables.

And I searched for java SE 9,10,11,12 and 13 and they dont even exist. I cant look this JRE up. It's just so confusing.

Also when I just try to compile my program (which has HashMap, but I clarified the types at the end), it says

> `Food.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations`
>   `Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details`
>   https://pastebin.com/Vw2UerDG

and I think the problem is the put() method but it doesnt make sense to me what operation of put in unsafe. It just doesnt seem to be...
Thanks

Comment: You must have compiled some of the classes with version 11?

Comment: You should have posted two questions, but for the second, the problem is in ´    public static void createAndSetupData(HashMap map)´.

Comment: Yeah I used intellij to compile the class in 1.8.0_161, but after executing it says:
Unable do acess jarfile app.jar

Comment: now on my desktop it works but not on my D:\ disk where intellij is...On D:\ it says could not find or load class Food. So it must be ambient variables. I hate this...

Comment: It can compile in D:\, but when I try to run it it says cant find or load...